# Solo 401k establishments costs - is it employer or employee?

Tags: accounting, s-corporation, solo-401k

I am on owner/employee for S-Corp. Took help from an administrator in establishing Solo 401k and paid some fees.

Can we write this fee as "business expense" (or) "is it EMPLOYEE expense"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up a 401k plan for a business is a business expense. It doesn't matter how many employees there are.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This 401K account has 3 different accounts like PRE, ROTH and AfterTax accounts. ROTH and AfterTax accounts are what raised this concern for me (my understanding is these 2 accounts are EMPLOYEE specific right?). I might be just nit picking things here.

Comment: @kosa thee's only one plan.